# Where can I find a printable keyboard layout when the option key is pressed?

Tags: keyboard

I am new to Apple, and I am new to use a Swiss French keyboard; unfortunately, a lot of useful characters are only available when the option key is pressed.

I would like to have an image of them available to be printed or to be quickly available, so that I can learn them. I have noticed that you can see the layout from Sys preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources > press the option key, but the image is too small and to be honest I do not know how to take a screenshot while pressing the option key.

Do you have any suggestion or good image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/10.14/mac/10.14) to see the keyboard instead of sys preferences.

Use the [Grab app](https://support.apple.com/guide/grab/welcome/mac) or the [Screenshot app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361) in Applications/Utilities to take a picture of it.

Comment: You can also drag the window by its corner to enlarge the Keyboard Viewer window so the characters are easier to see.

Comment: The **Grab** application does not exist in **macOS Mojave** and later. Use **/Applications/Screenshot** instead.

Comment: Interestingly, I have neither Grab nor Screenshot on Mojave - though the cmd/shft/3, 4, 5 all work as expected.

Comment: @user3439894 you are right about the Grab app, but likely they added one with an obvious name (screenshot)

Comment: @Tetsujin, On a clean install of both **macOS Mojave** and **macOS Catalina**, I have **/Applications/Screenshot**. Not sure why you don't have it too, but **⇧⌘5** does the same thing.